# How do I delete a row from a CSV in bash using sed or awk if a string exists in two columns?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I'm a beginner-mid level bash scripter and I'm not very familiar with working with csv files through terminal.

Through the hours of research I've wasted on this, I'm guessing `sed` or `awk` will be my best bet, I'm just not certain the best way to accomplish this.

The CSV is as follows:

> 

```
Owner,id,permission.deleted,permission.displayName,permission.domain,permission.emailAddress,permission.id,permission.photoLink,permission.role,permission.type
owner@domain.com,some_file_id,False,Display Name,domain.com,writer@domain.com,permissionidnumber,,writer,user
owner@domain.com,some_file_id,False,Display Name,domain.com,owner@domain.com,permissionidnumber,url,owner,user
```

My goal is to remove any lines where the owner is granted permissions from the original csv.

Ideally, I'd like something along the lines of `"If Column A (Owner) matches Column F (permission.emailAddress), delete the line"`

Desired Output - Replace existing CSV with:
The CSV is as follows:

> 

```
Owner,id,permission.deleted,permission.displayName,permission.domain,permission.emailAddress,permission.id,permission.photoLink,permission.role,permission.type
owner@domain.com,some_file_id,False,Display Name,domain.com,writer@domain.com,permissionidnumber,,writer,user
```

The command I'm running needs to use the CSV to read the permissions appropriately and I'm removing the owner since they retain ownership and if I try to grant it to them again, they receive an email and I'm trying to avoid spamming my users.

If I can't grab match two columns within the CSV and delete it from there, I can probably grab the `owner@domain.com` address and set it to a variable to use if that's easier. I just have to run this against ~100 unique users so the more I can automate, the better.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Regarding `I'm guessing sed or awk will be my best bet` - you are correct about awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, the following will execute orders of magnitude faster than a shell read loop with far simpler and far briefer code:

```
awk -F, '$1 != $6' file
```

For example:

```
$ awk -F, '$1 != $6' file
Owner,id,permission.deleted,permission.displayName,permission.domain,permission.emailAddress,permission.id,permission.photoLink,permission.role,permission.type
owner@domain.com,some_file_id,False,Display Name,domain.com,writer@domain.com,permissionidnumber,,writer,user
```

To modify the original file with GNU awk use `awk -i inplace -F, '$1!=$6' file` or with any awk `awk -F, '$1!=$6' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and it's very flexible, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `awk`.

```
$: cat x
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 3 4 5 3 7
5 6 3 4 5 6 7
7 8 3 4 5 6 7
9 0 3 4 5 9 7

awk '$1 == $6 { next } 1' x
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 6 3 4 5 6 7
7 8 3 4 5 6 7
```